# output or save the connections in the node editor maya

Tags: python, nodes, maya

recently I just started learning Maya. I want to take advantage of the node system of Maya to build a small visual scripting system. Is there a way to output or save the connections in the node editor in Maya?

Also, I know how to create a custom node, but I can't do anything to it. Is there a way to modify my custom node?
I'm aware of cmds library, and eventually I want to be able to control these nodes through a python script.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us your code if you have any, tell us what have you tried or what guides or tutorials you have looked into

Comment: When you speak of node system, are you talking about node editor or just node in general ?

Comment: Node editor is highend visual display of listRelatives + listConnections + attInfo commands .. so basically you can dump all this info to file ..

Comment: If you use the `.ma` file format you can -- with a bit of work -- follow all the nodes and connections in the scene.  However the nodes are not scripting nodes (like, say, Blueprints in Unreal) -- they are designed to be evaluated at runtime.